# Difference between list=[] and deleting all elements from the list

Tags: python

I was trying to make a list of lists in Python. I observed that list=[] and removing all elements from a list give different outputs. Can anybody explain why?

```
list11=[]
for i in range(10):
    temp=[]
    temp.append(i)
    list11.append(temp)
print(list11)
```

Output:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

---

```
temp=[1]
list11=[]
for i in range(2,10):
    temp.remove(i-1)
    temp.append(i)
    list11.append(temp)
print(list11)
```

Output:

```
[[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
```

I think the output in the second case is because temp is appended 8 times and in the last iteration the value of temp is [9]. I just do not understand why both outputs are different. What does the 'temp=[]' statement actually do?

Comment: `list11.append(temp)` does *not* store a **copy** of the list in `list11`; it stores *the list object*…

Comment: `list1 = []` just assign a new empty list to the name `list1`, it does _not_ change the list that was previously assigned to that name.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `temp=[]` creates a new empty list, whereas `temp.remove(i-1)` removes an item from an existing list to make it empty (in other words it mutates the list). So version one of the loop appends a new list on each iteration.  Version two of the loop appends the same list on each iteration. That means that in version two every item in `list11` is an instance of the same list.

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way to understand your code could be to print the intermediate states of the 2 lists.

This code:

```
print('Case 1')
num_list = []
for i in range(10):
    temp = []
    temp.append(i)
    num_list.append(temp)

    print('i: {} | temp: {:20s} | num_list: {}'.format(
        i, str(temp), str(num_list)))

print()
print('Case 2')
num_list = []
temp = [1, ]
for i in range(2,10):
    temp.remove(i-1)
    temp.append(i)
    num_list.append(temp)

    print('i: {} | temp: {:20s} | num_list: {}'.format(
        i, str(temp), str(num_list)))
```

gives this output:

```
Case 1
i: 0 | temp: [0]                  | num_list: [[0]]
i: 1 | temp: [1]                  | num_list: [[0], [1]]
i: 2 | temp: [2]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2]]
i: 3 | temp: [3]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
i: 4 | temp: [4]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
i: 5 | temp: [5]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
i: 6 | temp: [6]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
i: 7 | temp: [7]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]
i: 8 | temp: [8]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
i: 9 | temp: [9]                  | num_list: [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]

Case 2
i: 2 | temp: [2]                  | num_list: [[2]]
i: 3 | temp: [3]                  | num_list: [[3], [3]]
i: 4 | temp: [4]                  | num_list: [[4], [4], [4]]
i: 5 | temp: [5]                  | num_list: [[5], [5], [5], [5]]
i: 6 | temp: [6]                  | num_list: [[6], [6], [6], [6], [6]]
i: 7 | temp: [7]                  | num_list: [[7], [7], [7], [7], [7], [7]]
i: 8 | temp: [8]                  | num_list: [[8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8], [8]]
i: 9 | temp: [9]                  | num_list: [[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
```

In case 1, `num_list` contains 10 different lists (in each iteration a new `temp` list is created and appended) with each containing a single element.

In case 2, `num_list` contains 9 times a reference to the same list `temp`; in each iteration the same `temp` list is used and only its contents are modified, that is why it appears that the values are changing when in reality it is just the one `temp` list that is modified and included 9 times.

Does that help?